# How to import font file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, font-face, webfonts

CSS has a [`@font-face`](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) rule which allows us to "use" custom fonts.

Does JavaScript have this functionality?

More specifically, is it possible to "use" custom fonts without using the CSS `@font-face` rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to cause the browser to load a font from the network other than with a `@font-face` rule.  You could *theoretically* create that `@font-face` rule from JavaScript without having to use `document.write` (or `document.createElement("style")` etc), if instead you used the [CSS Object Model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/); but I wouldn't count on that to be implemented in any browser at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

## Update 2023: use [`FontFace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace)

As found on [CSS Font Loading API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API#examples):

```js
const url_to_font_name = 'URL to font'
const font_name = new FontFace('Font Name', `url(${url_to_font_name})`);
document.fonts.add(font_name);
// Work that does not require `font_name` to be loaded…
await font_name.load()
// Work that requires `font_name` to be loaded…
```

I'm separating the `url_to_font_name` variable out to indicate that it can be a *dynamically generated string*. This the *biggest benefit* I see to use JavaScript to load fonts compared to CSS.

Comment: So much win, so much easier than anything else I tried, and actually works. Modren web dev getting pretty snazzy.

Answer (score 4):

if you know CSS you can use `document.write` to append a style sheet dynamically... I guess that would count as using CSS, but it would work

Comment: heys this is cool, but are there other alternatives? (or cleaner hacks)

Comment: well, I don't know a whole lot about JavaScript, so this is really the only thing I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's not. Javascript can manipulate the DOM, but it doesn't care about formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental technology ["CSS Font Loading API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) that allows to load and use font in javascript. Currently working in chrome and firefox.

```
fetch('/static/media/ProximaNova-Regular.otf')
        .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer())
        .then(font => {
            const fontFace = new FontFace('Proxima-Nova', font);
            document.fonts.add(fontFace);
            document.body.style.fontFamily = '"Proxima-Nova", Arial';
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can:

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = '...';
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/QMZ8N/

this only adds a predefined font to an element.

This does **NOT** add a font style to the page. for that you might have to use CSS

Comment: "yes you can" but this is not what the question is asking.