# How to import fonts with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I need to complete a site without using **CSS** at all.

Every thing goes right but i don't know how to change my **font-family** with pure **JS**.

Does anyone know how it is possible to import fonts using **JS** only?

Thanks!

Comment: "I need to complete a site without using CSS at all." — Without more context, this is an unreasonable and nonsensical requirement. If there is a contextual reason that justifies it, then you almost certainly have an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and the question can't be reasonably answered without knowing that reason.

Comment: "font-family" is used to specify which of a set of *available* fonts should be used.  "import fonts" implies loading an external font file into the document to make it available to font-family. Which are you talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using Google's [Webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader), it's incredibly simple to use:

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    }
});
```

Which would allow you to use the massive web font library hosted by google [here](https://fonts.google.com/), without needing to explicitly specify the CSS.  You can use custom fonts as well if you're willing to use a style tag or a .css file (or you can inject the @font-face via javascript.)  There are other web font providers that work with the Webfontloader, just look on the github page.

If you're interested in learning how to do this manually in javascript, any query on injecting CSS via javascript will sort you, but, that's still technically using CSS.  Not sure if this/that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Best way for me...

Comment: @ZeevKatz — It doesn't meet your "No CSS" requirement though.

Comment: @Quentin why not?

Comment: @ZeevKatz — Because it injects CSS with JS.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear: the library is internally modifying the CSS of the page, but this is hidden from the user.  If you are interested in not having to explicitly modify the CSS yourself, and you're OK with using a compatible hosted web font, then this solution will work.  As has been stated already, there's no way to load a font without technically using CSS.  All javascript methods modify CSS.

Comment: If its hidden from users its what im looking for

Comment: @ZeevKatz — It isn't hidden from users. The code is there in the page. The results of the code are there in the DOM. The browser's Network tab will show the font file being downloaded. (Where did this "hidden from users" requirement come from? I draw your attention back to my comment on the question about this being an XY problem).

Comment: In this context user refers to the developer, "the user of the library."  All CSS is effectively hidden from the end-user.  When you have to go into the developer tools to see the CSS, that's a good description of 'hidden'.

Answer (score 20):

You say "pure JS" but most likely you are asking how to do it in the browser environment, which exposes a [Document Object Model or DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). Thus, you can use it with Javascript.

Unless this is a trick homework question, there should be no reason to avoid CSS, since the CSS is always available and that's the proper tool for styling things.

Changing the `font-family` of an element is easy:

```
element.style.fontFamily = "Arial, Sans Serif";
```

Now, to import a font, simply add a stylesheet or `<style>` element to the DOM, which has a `font-face` rule:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('href', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,700');
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

[There is no other way to do it currently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586845/how-to-import-font-file-using-javascript)

Comment: See the text immediately preceding what you quoted.

Comment: Telling people they shouldn't have asked the question they asked and then answering a different question doesn't seem like a great answer.

Comment: It is done often when the question is asking something impossible.

Comment: Not only that, but you have commented as much on that question yourself.

Comment: Yes, I made a comment that the question couldn't be reasonably answered in its present state. That's why I didn't try to answer it.

Comment: "there should be no reason to avoid CSS" - what if you require your app's configuration which contains the fonts to load? You'd rather duplicate the configuration into the CSS?