# how to use css codes in javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-face

I have a JS code:

```
fontCode += "*{font-family: " + sendFont.f + ", fontAwesome !important;}";
```

And I want to add some fonts by css `font-face`
so I added `font-face` codes to a css file called `font-face.css`
then i tried to include `font-face.css` file to the JS, I changed the js code to :

```
fontCode += "@import url('font-face.css'); *{font-family: " + sendFont.f + ", fontAwesome !important;}";
```

but it didn't work ! i dont't know how to use css `font-face` in my js file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
Please provide more of your code. What you have provided doesn't describe the problem in enough detail to give a full picture of the problem. I would suggest providing more code

Comment: do you want to dynamically change font in your html on some event using JS??

Comment: thank you friends, the JS file is: https://github.com/QWERTYUIOPYOZO/ReFont/blob/master/src/refont.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    }
});
```

[How to import fonts with pure JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706524/how-to-import-fonts-with-pure-js)

OR

```js
var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\
@font-face {\
    font-family: " + yourFontName + ";\
    src: url('" + yourFontURL + "') format('yourFontFormat');\
}\
"));

document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```

Please first search before ask a Question

[Font-Face changing via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355147/font-face-changing-via-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, I saw that topic, before. but it didn't help me. it doesn't work for me.

Comment: check the Console and tell why not

Comment: I can not, it's the first time i see JavaScript. Could you please check it by yourself? https://github.com/QWERTYUIOPYOZO/ReFont/blob/master/src/refont.js
thank you so much