# How can I Read a Font File That a User Uploads?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am working on a web-based project that is fully in Javascript. In it, I want users to be able to format their text exactly as they want. Naturally, I would like them to have the ability to upload their own fonts. However I'm not sure how to read the file they upload. I can take in the file, but I can't utilize their .ttf/.woff/woff2 etc. as an actual font file. I've used the FileReader API and have read in a ttf as a DataUrl, which puts it into base64. However I'm not sure how to turn it back into a file.

I've found this code from another post made on here, but it doesn't exactly do what I need it to do:

```
//read the file
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    <usersSelectedFile>.src = event.target.result;
});
var fontFile = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

With this, I get the file in base64. I know how to use `font-face`, but I've tried passing this fontFile in a font face style sheet but I got nothing from it.

My ultimate question is: How can I read a file in base64 as if it were a normal file? How should I reference it in `font-face`?

ALSO: I want to mention that I am trying to have this be stored in localStorage, as I wouldn't want any user-made changes to be global.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem that I would like to know the definitive solution to. The best I could find by searching around was [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55627399/13696669), that utilizes and API for this specific problem. I have not tested it as of this moment, but it seems reliable.

As for the localStorage issue, have you tried converting the file to a JSON string using JSON.stringify(), and then using localStorage.setItem('name',DATAHERE)? I am not sure if this works with files, but this is what I use for arrays and non-string information when saving to localStorage.

Sorry for not having anything concrete for you. I'm looking forward to working this out further if none of my recommendations helped you.

Comment: The code from that solution seems similar to what I'm using, however my issue would occur in that first fetch line. I'm not sure how to refer to the file. I can store it in local storage as a JSON.stringify string, but then if I were to use getItem('NAME') as the reference then it fails.

Comment: For fetch you put: fetch(fontFile). Since fontFile is a variable containing the URL of your file.